# Bush Leaves Withering Away

Tags: diseases, shrubs, dryness

Can somebody identify what is going on what is going on with my bushes here?
Is it some disease? Fungi? Virus? The weather in the area has not been punishingly hot though and this is the first time it has happened.

Location: Southern California

[image][image][image]

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Jumping to a conclusion; The bare ground and specific boundary of dead leaf area look like herbicide.